# How do you get the mean of a Eigen::MatrixXd column?

Tags: matrix, eigen, eigen3

I know that the functions [colwise()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox///classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a58837c81de446efbdb58da07b73a63c1) and [rowwise()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox///classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a6daa3a3156ca0e0722bf78638e1c7f28) exist in Eigen.

I saw this example here in Stack Overflow on [how to get the mean of a row using Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196545/eigen-class-to-take-mean-of-each-row-of-matrix-compute-centroid-of-the-column-v). However, it is not working for me.

Could somebody please clarify for me on how to get the mean of a particular row or column?

e.g. the 3rd row,

e.g. the 2nd column

Thanks a lot! Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as with the colwise/rowwise but on a single column/row:

```
MatrixXd mat(...);
// Fill the matrix
double meanCol3 = mat.col(3).mean();
double meanRow2 = mat.row(2).mean();
```